# How can I trigger autocomplete with multiple rules.

Tags: meteor

I have an autocomplete on a text box which shows zipcode, City, State. Currently when I start typing zipcode [e.g. 55414] the autocomplete works and starts to show the relevant zip,city and State. But I can't figure out how to trigger autocomplete if I start typing a city name. I want both of these triggers on the textbox. I tried to add another rule in the rules array but it doesn't work. ZipCodes collection has _id, city, state fields. _id is zipcode.

`Template.search.helpers({
    settings : function () {
        return {
            position: "bottom",
            limit: 20,
            rules: [{
                collection: ZipCodes,
                field: "_id",
                template: Template.userPill
            }]
        }
    }`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which package/library are you using for autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using [meteor-autocomplete](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete)
In that case you can use selector option

```js
Template.search.helpers({
    settings : function () {
        return {
            position: "bottom",
            limit: 20,
            rules: [{
                collection: ZipCodes,
                field: "_id",
                template: Template.userPill,
                selector: function(match) {
                   var regex;
                   regex = new RegExp(match, 'i');
                   return {
                       $or: [
                          {
                               '_id': regex
                          }, {
                               'city': regex
                          }
                       ]
                   };
                },

            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is too late for you, but it can be helpful to somebody in the future. Just do this inside your server-side `publish` function.

```
Meteor.publish('ZipCodesPublication', function(selector, options) {
  let limitTo = Math.abs(options.limit) > 50 ? 50 : options.limit,
    defaultSelector = selector._id,
    regEx = defaultSelector.$regex,
    regExOptions = defaultSelector.$options,
    customSeletor = {
        $or: [
          {
            city: {
              $regex: regEx,
              $options: regExOptions
            }
          },
          {
            _id: {
              $regex: regEx,
              $options: regExOptions
            }
          }
        ]
      };

  Autocomplete.publishCursor(Clients.find(customSeletor), this);
  this.ready();
});
```

And just do this on the client:

```
Template.search.helpers({
    settings : function () {
        return {
            position: "bottom",
            limit: 20,
            rules: [{
                collection: 'ZipCodes',
                subscription: 'ZipCodesPublication',
                field: "_id",
                template: Template.userPill
            }]
        }
    }
```